# A detail about Lie algebra?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I am reading GTM 9, and I am trying to compute a structure constants of an abstract Lie algebra using Jacobi identity: $[x[yz] + [y[zx]] + [z[xy]] = 0$. Apply it on $[x_l [x_i x_j] + [x_i [x_j x_l]] + [x_j [x_l x_i]] = 0$ and use $[x_i x_j] = \sum_k a_{ij}^k x_k$.

In the book the equation is 
[image]

My question is why need not we sum by index m? Just k?

Answer (score 0):

The structure constants are given by the Lie bracket of basis elements
$$
[e_i,e_j]=\sum_k a_{ij}^ke_k.
$$
Now apply this to $[e_i,[e_j,e_l]]$, and then to the Jacobi identity. This has been computed already here:

[What does the Jacobi identity impose on structure constants?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2317890/what-does-the-jacobi-identity-impose-on-structure-constants)

Comment: Yes I know that but when we compute [x[yz]] why don't we will have two indexes?

Comment: Yes, but the linear independence of the basis vectors then gives that the inner sum is zero. Have a look at the duplicate.